# Autocomplete isn't working for VS c++ mainly when i press enter it just inserts a new line

Tags: c++

example: when i type in "cou" it suggests cout I can hover over it but it doesn't autocomplete it. I already tried repairing visual studio and it is up to date

Answer (score 0):

The auto-complete key is <kbd>TAB</kbd>, not <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: okay let me specify, before when i pressed tab, it would automatically type in something like "std::cout <<" even when i just typed in "co" now it doesnt do that and basically just says that its undefined

Comment: @Automatonitronitrite: Well, it can't know that you intended `std::cout <<`. That's common, but `std::cout.rdbuf(` is also a possible completion.

Comment: yeah, no before okay so i would type in say "cout" and it would autocomplete to some pre set thing like "std::cout >> "your message here >> "/n";" but recently the feature has just completely dissapeared, the suggested square space wiht alist of suggested things appear but non of them get written on and if i press space it just adds a space, enter adds a new line and tab just adds an indent, and even double clicking doesnt do anything